# Steps and Scope tabs not appearing when I create an advanced workflow in kentico 9.0

Tags: kentico

I've got an advanced workflow that I'm trying to create in kentico 9.0 but when I create it on our dev or qa boxes the steps and scope tabs are not appearing.  I'm logging in as the Global Administrator and from what I'm seeing that user does have the Content -> Manage workflow permission.

The weird thing is I can create an advanced workflow on my local machine and the steps and scope appear fine, but when I export the site and import it into dev or qa I can no longer create a workflow with the steps and scope.  Also with the imported workflow I can no longer see the steps or scope.

Any ideas??

Comment: Have you tried resigning macros in those environments? I've found before that this can solve various problems including missing UI tabs. Ref: https://docs.kentico.com/k8/macro-expressions/macro-troubleshooting/working-with-macro-signatures#Workingwithmacrosignatures-Re-signingmacros

Comment: Thank you, resetting the macro's is what I needed.  If you put that in as an answer I'll mark yours as the correct answer.

Comment: Copied comment to new answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried resigning macros in those environments? I've found before that this can solve various problems including missing UI tabs. Ref: https://docs.kentico.com/k8/macro-expressions/macro-troubleshooting/working-with-macro-signatures#Workingwithmacrosignatures-Re-signingmacros

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it's enabled in the UI personalization application. You can find it under `CMS->Administration->Configuration->Workflows->Workflows->Edit workflow`. 
This is how it should look like in v9:

[image: UI Personalization - Workflows]

You should also enable Security debug in Settings and check what kind of check is preventing you from accessing certain functionality. 
[image: Security Debug]
However, if you're a global admin, you should have access everywhere. So I doubt this will help you in this case.

In some rare cases, it may happen that some UI elements go missing after you upgrade your instance (e.g. from version 8.2). This can happen when the best practices for developing new modules and extending the UI were not followed. If that's the case, you can explore the whole UI tree using the Modules application (if you navigate to a module and drill down to the User Interface tab). Modules with missing parents should appear in the root of the tree. You can try fixing the tree structure by changing parent elements of those broken elements. I'd also recommend checking the integrity by comparing the DB records (`CMS_UIElement` table) against a clean instance.

Comment: I updated the UI Personalization as you suggested but it still didn't fix it.  Tried to setup the debug for security and couldn't see that tab either. :-).  I did however write it to a file and I'm getting a TABPERMISSIONCHECK = 
  VALIDATEHASH = False  message on some of the tabs.  All of the CHECKPRIVILEGELEVEL 's are set to true, so I think that issue is fixed.      Any idea on what could be causing the hashing issue.  (I'm not seeing anything wrong when I look at the UI Elements.

Comment: thanks,  resetting the macro's is what I needed to do for it.

Comment: you need to resign the macros https://docs.kentico.com/k10/macro-expressions/troubleshooting-macros/working-with-macro-signatures#Workingwithmacrosignatures-Re-signingmacros

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Rocky mentions check out your IIS setup and feature installation on the servers.  You need to ensure WCF is installed and working properly for Advanced Workflow to work properly.

Comment: Note the WCF configuration for Kentico 9 is outlined here https://docs.kentico.com/k9/configuring-kentico/configuring-windows-communication-foundation